# How to set HLSL compiler tags with Visual Studio 2010 and XNA

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, branch, hlsl

Referring to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619520/hlsl-compiler-optimizes-strange/16622841?noredirect=1#16622841), how do I set the tag [branch] for the HLSL compiler in Visual Studio 2010 compiling fx files in an XNA project?

Comment: As in the linked documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you write those hints direct before the if. You don't need to tell something globally to the compiler.

Comment: How can I mark this (comment that answers my question) as answer?

Comment: That isn't possible. I've copied the comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the linked documentation ([doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) you write those hints direct before the if. You don't need to tell something globally to the compiler.